# kOS Print Pitch of Heading?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I'm writing a kOS script to launch and land a booster, and I'm currently working on the display. I ran the command `print steer(pitch) at(0, 3)`.

"steer" is the variable used to store target direction, using many functions in the form of `set steer to heading(90, 90)`.

When I tried to print out the target pitch of my craft, I received the error:

> Attempted to make a function call on a non-invokable object: steer.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you simply have a syntax error. A [direction](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/math/direction.html) like your `steer` is a [structure](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/language/features.html#structures), not a [function](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/language/user_functions.html#calling-a-function). To access its `pitch` property, you need to write `steer:pitch`, not `steer(pitch)`.

---

Also note that, as far as I can tell, the name `steer` has no special significance in kOS; it's just an arbitrary variable name.  There *is* a special [bound variable](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/bindings.html) named `steering` (not `steer`) that is used for "cooked" [flight control](https://ksp-kos.github.io/KOS/commands/flight.html) with the command:

```
lock steering to <expression>
```

where `<expression>` is any vector or direction.  However, it seems that [quite a few](https://www.google.com/search?q=kos+%22lock+steering+to+steer%22) kOS scripts will first assign the desired direction to a normal user variable (which might be named e.g. `steer`) and then lock `steering`to that variable.

I'm not 100% sure why they do that, but I suspect it may be a performance optimization: when you `lock` a variable to an expression, kOS will recalculate the value of that expression every time the value of the variable is read.  And kOS internally reads the value of `steering` many times every second.  Thus, if you only want to lock the steering to a constant direction, it's probably faster to first calculate that direction and assign it to a normal variable, and then lock `steering` to that variable.

Anyway, the point of all this is that a command like `print steer:pitch` will only print the pitch component of whatever direction you've assigned to the variable `steer`.  This may or may not actually have anything to do with the pitch that kOS is currently trying to steer your ship towards; that depends on whether you've locked `steering` to `steer` or not.